# In nestJs while generating service/controller/module getting console error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

```
using this command for generating - nest g service database

getting this error:-
nest: File C:\Users\Binni Kumari\AppData\Roaming\npm\nest.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
```

https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nest g service database
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```